How to render a component in a fresh page in react app
I have all the components with me and the links were also working. Below is the code for App.jsx
import { useState } from 'react';
import Home from "./Components/Home";
import Secondquestion from "./Components/Secondquestion";
import Nextquestion from './Components/Nextquestion';
import {Link,Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'; 
import './App.css';

function App() {  
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/home">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/next">Nextquestion</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/second">Secondquestion</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/home" element={<Home></Home>}></Route>
        <Route path="/next" element={<Nextquestion/>}></Route>
        <Route path="/second" element={<Secondquestion/>}></Route>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App


code for main.jsx
import { StrictMode } from 'react'
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.jsx'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import './index.css'

createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </StrictMode>,
)


The links were working but it was rendering in the same page. But i want to get them in a fresh page. How to do that.

Do you mean open in a new tab? You can use target="_blank" on the Link component

if i put it 
Home its rendering new tab. what i exactly want is the Nextquestion page to be rendered in a blank  page such that all the other components vanishes
